# XNA with TaskFactory execution times when executing SetData on Texture in a loop

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, xna-4.0, taskfactory

Though this question is about an implementation in XNA, i think it is a better fit for a more general C# forum. I am using the TaskFactory with XNA to initialize additional resources while presenting a loading screen to the user. The code is similar to this:

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeInitialStuff()) 
          .ContinueWith((x) => BuildALevel(x.Result)) 
          .ContinueWith((x) => DoSomeFinalizingStuff(x.Result)) 
          .ContinueWith((x) => NotifyThatIAmFinished());
```

I have logged the times needed, and my `DoSomeFinalizingStuff` method will take longer when my main window is in focus. `DoSomeFinalizingStuff` actually writes to a 400x400 Texture2D (which is not displayed in the process, just created and modified) using the SetData method.

AVG Time taken when in focus and visible: ~5000ms (up to 10k+ at times)
AVG Time taken when not in focus (and not visible): ~100ms

The time measured is actual execution time of `DoSomeFinalizingStuff`. Thats at AVG a factor of 50 difference, i am pretty curios, why that is the case.

When running the debugger both all chained tasks together need about a second to complete. When run without debugging and no interaction it is a lot slower, usually the loading screen sits there for about 10-15 seconds until its complete.

I can "trigger" the Task to execute faster when i switch focus away from my main window. As soon as i switch away, the function gets executed.

If i remove the SetData() calls, performance is the same as when debugging or windows i inactive.

Why is this happening and is there a way to modify this behavior?

Comment: As a side note, you don't need the parentheses around `x`.

Comment: What exactly happens during that time? Is the task actually executing or waiting to be executed? If it's executing, what exactly is it doing?

Comment: @svick the task is executed and writes onto an existing Texture2d. the operation is always the same and takes less than a sec when debugging (or clicking on another window, like bringin VS into foreground) but up to 15 secs when doing no interaction (press F5 and wait till completion). I know because i added System.Debug calls in the method and observed this behavior in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a synchronization issue.

One *possible* cause is that `ContinueWith` inherits `TaskScheduler` (if you run it from a task with scheduler initialized with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` it will have it too). Try calling you `ContinueWith` this way: `ContinueWith(...,TaskScheduler.Default)`.

If it's not the case, then try looking at 'Parallel Tasks' and other thread-related windows during debugging. It might help you identify the problem.

Comment: @UrbanEsc Well, that was just a possible cause. (And usually it causes deadlocks, not slowdowns.) Anyway, I'm 99.9999% sure that TPL is not to blame here. Good luck.

Comment: I don't want to blame :) you might be right, the behavior i am observing might be correct, but i need to understand why. It looks like the main thread, the game, is busy with all those Update() and Draw() calls, so might that be a reason for TPL to give my tasks a lower prio?

Comment: AFAIK, TPL just uses `ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem` internally. You can get the running thread priority using `Thread.CurrentThread.Priority`, but I think you'll find it normal. I don't know about XNA, but maybe that texture modification is slow because of some concurrent issues. You can verify it by removing only texture mutation leaving all computations in place... Good luck.

Comment: Indeed, if i remove my setdata calls, it executes in less than a second (same performance as when in background or debugging).